# I'm not able to extract kannada text from .html files from browser

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program that get corpus from web using the `wget` command of the shell. While using `lynx -dump` command to extract data from HTML, this is working fine from the command prompt. But when I am tying to run the same program from the browser, the kannada text from the files is not extracting from files. I am able to get only the English text. My program is like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type:text/html;
charset=utf-8\n\n";
use CGI;
use Cwd;
my $ftpname="www.kuvempu.com";
chomp($ftpname);
system("wget --mirror -p --convert-links -x --reject=gif $ftpname");
print("please wait a while data has been downloding");
system("rm -rf $ftpname/en");
system("rm -rf $ftpname/images");
system("rm -rf $ftpname/source");
my @files = glob("$ftpname/*");
foreach my $f(@files) {
    system("lynx -dump $f > $f.txt");
    }
open fp,">>$ftpname-text-file" || die "coun't noe create $ftpname-text-file";
my @outfiles=glob("$ftpname/*.txt");
foreach my $f1(@outfiles) {
    open(aaa,"<$f1"); print fp <aaa>; close(aaa);
    }
close(fp);
system("grep -v http $ftpname-text-file > a");
system("grep -v file a > b");
system("sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z]//g' b > c");
system("egrep -v -x '.{1,10}' c > d");
system("grep -v '\]' d > e");
system("grep -v '©' e > f");
system("grep -v '[0-9] - [0-9]' f > g");
system("sed 's/^ //g' g > h");
system("sed 's/^-//g' h > i");
```

Comment: As you posted it, your perl is just a very long comment. Please [edit] your post, remove the existing blob of stuff, and paste your code. Then select your code and click on the `{}` button.

Comment: @user3395299 welcome to stackoverflow, please read how to post question efficiently.

Comment: Why do you use files? Reading the input into a Perl array would simplify the script enormously. It is also not entirely unlikely that something in those `system` commands is not properly set up for your character set. Is it UTF-8, or some legacy encoding? Is your locale correctly set up?

Answer (score 1):

You have `print "Content-Type:text/html;` then `use CGI;`, you never use CGI. Either don't load it or use it properly.

```
use CGI;
my $q = $CGI->new();
print $q->header();
```

The remainder of your script is just a mess of system calls. Debug your system calls or write this in Perl.